# Fill column B based on column A and B pairing

Tags: excel, vba

Each report in column A has a corresponding location in column B

Column B has locations to many of the reports, but not all.

I need to fill in locations in column B where blank.

```
    A    B     ->    A    B
    1    a           1    a
    1                1    a
    2    b           2    b
    2    b           2    b
    2                2    b
    3                3    
    3                3
```

I've tried =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$A:$B,0)),"",B1), but I'm definitely missing something. I also have 35000 rows, looking to process it all at once.

Comment: Column A is sorted ascended. It has a value in each of the 35000 rows. Column B is partially filled with many empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is to use an index/match function.  This needs to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

> =INDEX($B$1:$B$7,MATCH(A1,IF($B$1:$B$7="","",$A$1:$A$7),0))

What match does is return the index number of the cell, so if it was found in the 3rd cell of a range it would return 3 not the cell value.

Inside the match we have an if statement that puts a blank in the array if the cell in B is blank and the value from cell A if its not.

We then match the value in cell A1 to this array which will return a filled column B with a matching column A if it exists.

The index allows you to pick a cell in a range based on the cell index (which match returns).

This formula is in cell C1 with the data in A1:B7.

Comment: I updated the formula to =INDEX($B$1:$B$35195,MATCH(A2,IF($B$1:$B$35195="","",$A$1:$A$35195),0)) to fit the range of the sheet. Auto-filling didn't seem to work as I was typing this, but it just needed to finish loading and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah being an array formula it takes a lot of resources.  For all your cells it has to run 35,000 cells that each have 35,000 if statements.  Unless you need it dynamic I would recommend copying and pasting values or turning calculation to manual.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just doing it once, so no programming is necessary.

If so, first sort your data on **Column_A,Column_B**. Then off to the right, create a calculated column from Column B that overwirites any blank with the value form the preceding row exactly when the two rows have the same Column_A value.

Then Copy the column and Paste Special -> Values over top of Column_B.